# jQ change events from click to hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need change event from click to hover
Hehe is code in action: [link](http://www.werb.pl/domki/) - to see effect click "Karta tatrzanska"

Here is the code I have :

```
 $jQuery(document).ready(function () {
     function slideSlideBar() {
         if (clicked == true) {
             if (isExtended == 0) {
                 $jQuery(slideBarTabImage).attr('src', $jQuery(slideBarTabImage).attr('src').replace(/(\.[^.]+)$/, '-active$1'));
                 $jQuery(slideBarContents).animate({
                     width: conWidth + 'px'
                 }, slideSpeed);
                 isExtended = 1;
             } else {
                 $jQuery(slideBarTabImage).attr('src', $jQuery(slideBarTabImage).attr('src').replace(/-active(\.[^.]+)$/, '$1'));
                 $jQuery(slideBarContents).animate({
                     width: '0px'
                 }, slideSpeed);
                 isExtended = 0;
             }
             clicked = false;
         } else {
             if (isExtended == 0) {} else {
                 $jQuery(slideBarContents).animate({
                     width: conWidth + 'px'
                 }, 0);
                 $jQuery(slideBar).animate({
                     width: fullWidth + 'px'
                 }, 0);
             }
         }
     }

     $jQuery(slideBarTab).hover(slideSlideBar());
     window.slideSlideBar = slideSlideBar;
 });
```

Comment: Replace `.hover()` with `.click()`

Comment: use this code it may help you `$( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
 // js
    $('.someclass').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        },
        function(){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
//css
.someclass{display:none;}
.someclass.active{display:block;}
```